# Load another data on single listview click

Tags: android, listview, animation

I am new Android Guys so please help me out. I am working on a App in which there is a two Listview one at the top and second at the bottom. In Bottom listview few cards come by animation and i have to select one and the cards again with the help of animation goes up and set to top listview and the bottom listview the remaining cards replace by new cards. I am able to use the listview once but unable to load the cards again on the bottom listview. I am posting my code here please help me out of this guys. Thanks

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public class Item {
    Drawable ItemDrawable;
    String ItemString;
    Item(Drawable drawable, String t){
        ItemDrawable = drawable;
        ItemString = t;
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView icon;
    TextView text;
}

public class ItemsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Item> list;
    int position;

    ItemsListAdapter(Context c, List<Item> l){
        context = c;
        list = l;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        // reuse views
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowImageView);
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowTextView);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(list.get(position).ItemDrawable);
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).ItemString);

        return rowView;
    }

    public List<Item> getList(){
        return list;
    }
}

List<Item> items1, items2;
HorizontalListView listView1, listView2;
ItemsListAdapter myItemsListAdapter1, myItemsListAdapter2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView1 = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    listView2 = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview2);
    initItems();

    myItemsListAdapter1 = new ItemsListAdapter(this, items1);
    myItemsListAdapter2 = new ItemsListAdapter(this, items2);
    listView1.setAdapter(myItemsListAdapter1);
    listView2.setAdapter(myItemsListAdapter2);

    final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
    listView1.startAnimation(animScale);

            listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Item selectedItem = (Item) (parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                    ItemsListAdapter associatedAdapter = (ItemsListAdapter) (parent.getAdapter());
                    List<Item> associatedList = associatedAdapter.getList();
                    Item associatedItem = associatedList.get(position);
                    if (removeItemToList(associatedList, associatedItem)) {

                        view.invalidate();
                        associatedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        ItemsListAdapter list2Adapter = (ItemsListAdapter) (listView2.getAdapter());
                        List<Item> list2List = list2Adapter.getList();

                        addItemToList(list2List, selectedItem);
                        list2Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });

    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowImageView)).setImageResource(R.drawable.card1);
        }
    });
}

private void initItems(){
    items1 = new ArrayList<Item>();
    items2 = new ArrayList<Item>();

    TypedArray arrayDrawable = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.resicon);
//        TypedArray arrayText = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.restext);

    for(int i=0; i<arrayDrawable.length(); i++){
        Drawable d = arrayDrawable.getDrawable(i);
 //   String s = arrayText.getString(i);
        Item item = new Item(d,"");
        items1.add(item);
    }
    arrayDrawable.recycle();
 //  arrayText.recycle();
}

private boolean removeItemToList(List<Item> l, Item it){
    boolean result = l.remove(it);
    return result;
}

private boolean addItemToList(List<Item> l, Item it){
    boolean result = l.add(it);
    return result;
}

}
```

XML(activity_main)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="4dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pane1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pane2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/listview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

arrays.xml(card image)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<array name="resicon">
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>
    <item>@drawable/card</item>

</array>
</resources>
```